# PHP Curl IIS7 throwing 500 error

Tags: php, curl, iis-7, windows-7-x64

I just uncomment curl in the php.ini and started trying to use it in my small php app.  First off my php works fine for most everything else. Its able connect to mysql DB.  The error Im getting

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Which isn't exactly helpful.

Im Using

IIS 7
PHP 5
Windows 7

Comment: What's the actual error?  There will be more information in one of your logs.

Comment: Which log? The event logs also doesn't provide much information.

Comment: Perhaps PHP isn't configured to log?  Check your PHP.ini for details.

Comment: could please suggest what I should set in the PHP.ini to produce to correct logs.

Comment: If you open your PHP.ini file, you will see an entire section dedicated towards logging.  Set the settings to what you need for your system.  You're on Windows, so you can configure it to log to the event log, or simply write to a file.